# Fractional scaling resets after logout in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, scaling

Fractional scaling works fine on my dual monitor and can setup monitor location, but when I logout (not even reset) I lose all the settings and it goes back to 100%. Any icons move to the second monitor.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try the proposed solution?

Answer (score 3):

This has been a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1825593) in Ubuntu for over a year and recently a fix got released. However, from what I can see this fix has not been released for any stable Ubuntu version. Let's hope that happens soon.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason for your problem, but I guess you can deal with it by setting fractional scaling upon logging in.

For that sake, you can use

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
```

for Wayland ([this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230208/fractional-scaling-does-not-work-properly-ubuntu-20-04#comment2071635_1230208) confirms a working case), or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']"
```

for X11.
Check with

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

your display server

And for the text,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.2
```

---

Another option (a hack).
Use the **Xorg** solution proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030032/226614). Set gnome scaling to 2, and then scale down with `xrandr`.
Actually, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056366/226614), does it with a shell script, as I am suggesting.

---

If none of this works, you can install `dconf-editor`, and tinker with these `gsettings` to see the output of various setting key changes, to learn details about your system, and possibly find the right combination that works.

---

**Please post feedback**.

**Refs**:

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-enable-hidpi-fractional-scaling.html

https://www.debugpoint.com/2020/01/how-to-enable-fractional-scaling-in-ubuntu-18-04-19-10/

... and quite a few others

Answer (score 1):

installing update in software updater GUI solves the problem for me.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer a bit? What was updated? Ubuntu itself, just the software updater, or something else? Your answer might help others in the future.