# Unable to increase Screen Scale in Ubuntu

Tags: display, screen, scaling

I have been using ubuntu for almost 1 month now and was able to increase the scale to 125% but one day suddenly it is back to 100% and I am unable to change, when I try to click on 125% it automatically chooses 200% . The text is very small if it is at 100%

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

[This is my terminal output of the command lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwio0.png)

I have a benq2480 monitor

My input was not working so I followed this guide
[https://atish3604.medium.com/solved-bluetooth-headset-mic-not-working-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-86a5236444d0#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20uninstall%20ofono,if%20you%20have%20them%20installed.&text=If%20it's%20still%20not%20showing,check%20if%20it%20works%20now](https://atish3604.medium.com/solved-bluetooth-headset-mic-not-working-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-86a5236444d0#:%7E:text=You%20need%20to%20uninstall%20ofono,if%20you%20have%20them%20installed.&text=If%20it%27s%20still%20not%20showing,check%20if%20it%20works%20now).

But even after this for a while the screen was working fine

Please let me know if you need any other informations

Thanks for the help :)

Edit: I solved this , my  nvidia gpu drivers were not installed properly after installing it . I am able to fractional scale

[Fractional Scaling does not work properly ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230208/fractional-scaling-does-not-work-properly-ubuntu-20-04)

this thread also helped

Comment: You've not provided any release details, plus given clues as to what if anything you did in the last session **before** it was locked on the choices you have now (*which is likely why you can't change it now*)

Comment: Some information about your hardware is going to be required, in addition to which version of Ubuntu you're running. This may be the result of a video driver limitation. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the brand/model of machine you're using (2) the Terminal output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`. With this, it *may* be possible to offer some assistance 

Comment: Thanks for reaching out . I have edited the post and added the details , Please let me know if you need any other information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fractional Scaling does not work properly ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230208/fractional-scaling-does-not-work-properly-ubuntu-20-04)